# Tkinter issue with the label in if block

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, label

I have an issue with the label in if statement in tkinter, also similar with the try/except block.

I am trying to create a Pokemon fight simulator based on the data from csv.

This is pulling data from csv, but the exemption mechanism, when someone puts a name that is not in base is not working.

```
     else:
            my_label = Label(root, text="Oops! I don't think we got such Pokemon archive.", font=("Comic Sans", 20))
            my_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

I want the program to show additional label with the text but it's not working. It's freezing a program instead so I am not able to discover the error, nor able to figure out the reason. Could someone please advise me how to fix this?

```
   from tkinter import *


def create_pokemon_b():
    import pandas as pd
    df_pokemons = pd.read_csv('/home/js/PycharmProjects/untitled/main_Pokemon.csv')
    while True:
        name = str(entry_pokename_b.get()).capitalize()
        if name in list(df_pokemons['pokename']):
            while True:
                level = entry_pokelevel_b.get()
                try:
                    level = int(level)
                    speed = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                    'speed'].mean())
                    hp = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                 'hp'].mean())
                    att = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                  'attack'].mean())
                    defense = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                      'defense'].mean())
                    type1 = str(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                    'type1'].unique()[0])
                    stats = Label(root,
                                  text='{} on level {}: \nType = {} \nHP = {} \nDefense = {} \nSpeed = {}\nAttack = {}\n'.format(
                                      name, level, type1, hp, defense, speed, att), font=("Comic Sans", 15))
                    stats.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=6, rowspan=6)
                    global poke_b
                    poke_b = tuple(type1, name, level, speed, hp, defense, att)

                except ValueError:
                    error = Label(root, text="Oops! I don't think we got such Pokemon archive.",
                                  font=("Comic Sans", 20))
                    error.grid(row=7, column=1)
        else:
            my_label = Label(root, text="Oops! I don't think we got such Pokemon archive.", font=("Comic Sans", 20))
            my_label.grid(row=1, column=1)


root = Tk()

my_label = Label(root)
my_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
#entry fields where name and level of pokemon B are entered

label_pokename = Label(root, text='Enter name of Pokemon A.',font=("Comic Sans", 15))
label_pokelevel = Label(root, text='What is it\'s level?',font=("Comic Sans", 15))

entry_pokename = Entry(root, width=40, font=("Comic Sans", 15))
entry_pokelevel = Entry(root, width=40, font=("Comic Sans", 15))

label_pokename.grid(row=0)
entry_pokename.grid(row=1)
label_pokelevel.grid(row=2)
entry_pokelevel.grid(row=3)

#statistics field

stats = Label(root)
stats.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=6, rowspan=6)

#button starting function used to pull pokemon data from the csv

button_a = Button(root, text='Search',font=("Comic Sans", 15),command=create_pokemon_a)
button_a.grid(row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here and your question is not specific enough. What error are you getting? What line is causing the problem? Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited my question to be more specific and allow better understanding of my issue.

Comment: Well I can tell you the `while True` statement is likely the cause of your code freezing. Do not use `while` statements or `sleep()` in the same thread as tkinter as they will block the mainloop and freeze the program. That said move your imports all to the the top of your code. Do not put your imports in a function. Every time someone presses the button you import again and again for no reason. It just needs to happen once at the start of your code. Also put your `global` at the start of your function. Its just easier to read and deal with.

Comment: I agree with everthing @Mike said. Plus in this case your `while True:` appears to be an infinite loop (even if a `ValueError` occurs) which would be wrong in a non-tkinter app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mike - SMT, Thanks for answer. Indeed when I removed while statement the code started to work.

```
def create_pokemon_b():
    import pandas as pd
    df_pokemons = pd.read_csv('/home/js/PycharmProjects/untitled/main_Pokemon.csv')
        name = str(entry_pokename_b.get()).capitalize()
        if name in list(df_pokemons['pokename']):
                level = entry_pokelevel_b.get()
                try:
                    level = int(level)
                    speed = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                    'speed'].mean())
                    hp = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                 'hp'].mean())
                    att = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                  'attack'].mean())
                    defense = int(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                      'defense'].mean())
                    type1 = str(df_pokemons[(df_pokemons['pokename'] == name) & (df_pokemons['pokelevel'] == level)][
                                    'type1'].unique()[0])
                    stats = Label(root,
                                  text='{} on level {}: \nType = {} \nHP = {} \nDefense = {} \nSpeed = {}\nAttack = {}\n'.format(
                                      name, level, type1, hp, defense, speed, att), font=("Comic Sans", 15))
                    stats.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=6, rowspan=6)
                    global poke_b
                    poke_b = tuple(type1, name, level, speed, hp, defense, att)

                except ValueError:
                    error = Label(root, text="Oops! I don't think we got such Pokemon archive.",
                                  font=("Comic Sans", 20))
                    error.grid(row=7, column=1)
        else:
            my_label = Label(root, text="Oops! I don't think we got such Pokemon archive.", font=("Comic Sans", 20))
            my_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
```